# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable in python function

Tags: python, dataframe, counter

I have written the following codes:

```
def summarize_withoutStations(path, month):
    calculate_withoutStations(getFiles(path, month))

def calculate_stations (allFiles):

    result = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Date','Mid Ebb Total','Mid Flood Total','Mid Ebb Control','Mid Flood Control'])

    Mid_Ebb_unique_stations = []
    Mid_Flood_unique_stations = []

    for file_ in allFiles:
        print('Checking' +str(file_))
        xls = pd.ExcelFile(file_)
        df = xls.parse('General Impact')
        if len(df) > 300:
            print('Please check if there are more than one month data in the excel')
            cont = input('Please type Y to continue, N to exit')
            if cont == 'Y':
                continue
            if cont == 'N':
                break

        Mid_Ebb = df[df['Tidal Mode'] == "Mid-Ebb"] #filter
        Mid_Flood = df[df['Tidal Mode'] == "Mid-Flood"] #filter
        Mid_Ebb_stations = Mid_Ebb['Station'].unique()
        Mid_Flood_stations = Mid_Flood['Station'].unique()
        Mid_Ebb_unique_stations.extend(list(Mid_Ebb_stations))
        Mid_Flood_unique_stations.extend(list(Mid_Flood_stations))

    Ebb_list = Counter(Mid_Ebb_unique_stations)
    Flood_list = Counter(Mid_Flood_unique_stations)

    total_Mid_Ebb = sum(Ebb_list.values())
    total_Mid_Flood = sum(Flood_list.values())

    print('Ebb tide list: ' + str(Ebb_list))
    print('Flood tide list:' + str(Flood_list))
    print('Ebb tide total: {} Flood totaltide: {}'.format(total_Mid_Ebb, total_Mid_Flood))

    df_Ebb_list = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Ebb_list, orient='index')
    df_Flood_list = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Flood_list, orient='index')

    print(df_Ebb_list)
    print(df_Flood_list)

    return df_Ebb_list, df_Flood_list
```

when I call `a,b = func.summarize_withStations(path, month)`, it gives TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable.

Dataframes are not printed too.

Comment: Which line does it error on? Please also read: [mcve].

Comment: a,b = func.summarize_withStations(path, month)

Comment: when I do it in a non-function way (check the files one by one), I can get the dataframe (df_Ebb_list and df_Flood_list)

Comment: can you post the full traceback. There will be a line within this function which is failing

Comment: Please read and don't ignore: [mcve]

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-2dc3f0a28df4> in <module>()
----> 1 a,b = func.summarize_withStations(path, month)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

this is the whole thing.

Comment: I also tried to just return the counter. But it gives the similar error: NoneType

Answer (score 0):

I have done something silly.

```
def summarize_withoutStations(path, month):
    calculate_withoutStations(getFiles(path, month))
```

have no return statement.